# Leaflet imageOverlay click event

Tags: image, onclick, leaflet, mouseevent

I need an on click event on image overlays. 
According to the documentation [Leaflet documentation imageOverlay](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#imageoverlay) (as far as I understand it correctly) 
I can use the interactivity option to receive mouse events.

> If true, the image overlay will emit mouse events when clicked or hovered.

I thought it would work something like that:

```
let newOverlay = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds, {opacity:0.5, interactive: true}); 

newOverlay.on('click', function(d) {alert('I have been clicked ' # this)});
```

My final goal is to get the pixel coordinates of the click event, relative to the image on which the click event happened.

Can someone spot my error or is there another approach?
I tried for hours, but I did not succeed :(

I am thankful for every help.

Kind regards

Niklas

Comment: Seems to work as expected https://jsfiddle.net/7xoraevf/ . I assumed your overlay is actually added to the map

Comment: Thank you very much nikoshr. Your example helped me a lot! In fact the problem was, that in a hidden place (not my code ;-)) a layer was drawn on top of every other layer. So the event was not triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little mistake

Change **#** to **+** so you will get alert message: **I have been clicked [object Object]**

> alert('I have been clicked ' **#** this)

to

> alert('I have been clicked ' **+** this)

```
let newOverlay = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds, {opacity:0.5, interactive: true}); 

newOverlay.on('click', function(d) {alert('I have been clicked ' + this)});
```